# Magento 2 Deploy CSS Updates

Tags: css, magento, deployment, continuous-integration, magento2

I am trying to figure out a way to move in css updates in production mode without any downtime or maintenance mode enabled.

For example, if I update something in theme's style.css, I will need to run the commands below to get the css updates included in the merged css file.

rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush

But this will create downtime. Running deploy command along will not update the css.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can try php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f, after that, php bin/magento cache:flush. This work for my Magento 2 in production mode

Comment: You can use something that some people call a shadow environment. It's a folder with a copy of your Magento file system. You do all of your commands, composer and file system work/alterations that are not `bin/magento setup:upgrade` then on linux you rsync it to your live folder and then flush the cache if `setup:upgrade` isn't required otherwise it's a bit of downtime with `setup:upgrade --keep-generated` and maintenance mode. I've tried this in a limited amount in staging but this isn't a full answer so you'll need to work out the details on your own.